# STS AssumeRole error: AWS Access Key "does not exist in our records"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I'm working on an API Gateway/Lambda-based project. The request flow works as follows:

- API Gateway passes request to Authorizer lambda
- Authorizer lambda calls `sts.assumeRole()` and successfully generates an `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`
- Key/secret are passed to request handler lambda via authorizer context
- Request handler lambda uses the given `accessKeyId/secretAccessKey` to attempt to access items from an S3 bucket

Every step of the process is working (confirmed via console log), except for the final one. When I attempt to use the generated credentials, I get the following error message:

```
   {
      "message": "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.",
      "code": "InvalidAccessKeyId",
      "region": null,
      "time": "2019-07-19T22:05:05.817Z",
      "requestId": "...",
      "extendedRequestId": "...",
      "statusCode": 403,
      "retryable": false,
      "retryDelay": 68.28400384749038
    }
```

I know this hints strongly that there's something about STS that I don't understand, but I haven't been able to figure out what. (For example, does AWS de-allocate the generated role when the authorizer lambda finishes running?)

**Why would AWS be rejecting a freshly-generated pair of credentials, and report this error message?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the AssumeRole documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html), the returned `SessionToken` must also be included in any request using the generated credentials.

> When you make a call using temporary security credentials, the call must include a session token, which is returned along with those temporary credentials. AWS uses the session token to validate the temporary security credentials.

I had assumed that the generated credentials were exactly like user access keys, and expected the calls to succeed using only those two pieces of information.

Comment: This is the answer I needed.  Most search results are the "check your spelling" kind of problem.  It appears that you can't these provided credentials externally to authenticate as a USER.  For example, third party integrations where you need to provide the usual (key/secret) pair to access individual items.  Assuming a role doesn't produce usable credentials outside of a session that must include the session token.